# Finding P-Value and confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval, p-value

I am given that the percentage of births that are girls is 48.5%, a study found out of $329$ children, $157$ of them were girls, I need to use binomial distribution to find a P-value for the test.  I found that the probability of exactly or fewer than $157$ out of $329$ is $.4101$ which is 41.01% and exactly or more than $157$ out of $329$ is $.6321$ or 63.21%, I just wanted to verify what I thought was correct. I also need to find a 95% confidence interval for the probability that a child is a girl, I am unsure how to find the standard deviation with this problem though? Thank you in advance!

Comment: For proportions, the standard error is $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$

Comment: @RobertTheTutor so would it just be .0275?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this problem:

**The exact binomial test
and associated confidence interval.** In R, this procedure is
implemented as `binom.test`. The 2-sided version of this test
with $H_0: p = 0.485$ against $H_a: p\ne 0.585$ is shown below.
[The 2-sided test is the default; an extra argument is required
to request a 1-sided test, in either direction.]

```
binom.test(157, 329, p = 0.485)

        Exact binomial test

data:  157 and 329
number of successes = 157, number of trials = 329, 
 p-value = 0.783
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.485
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4221301 0.5326912
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.4772036
```

Because the P-value $0.485 > 0.05 = 5\%$ we do not reject $H_0.$
In other words, we do not find the estimated probability $\hat p = 157/329$ of girl births to be statistically significantly different than the hypothetical value $p = 0.085$ at the 5% level.

Under the assumption that $p =0.985, n = 329$ we find
$P(X \le 157) = 0.41.$ That is the probability observing an $x \le \mu = 159.565$ is about $0.41.$ Some programs just double
this one-sided P-value to get the P-value of a 2-sided test.
However, the probability that $x \ge \mu$ by the same amount
is a little smaller, so the two-sided P-value shown in R output above is $0.78.$

```
pbinom(157, 329, 0.485)
[1] 0.4101271
mu = 329*0.485; mu
[1] 159.565
```

In the plot below, the bars show the PDF (or PMF) of
$\mathsf{Binom}(n = 329, p = 0.485),$ the vertical blue
line is at $\mu = np,$ the lower vertical red line is the
observed value of $X,$ and the P-value is the sum of the
heights of the bars in the two tails outside of the two
vertical red lines. [The PDF is almost, but not *exactly* symmetrical about $\mu.]$

[image]

The confidence interval $( 0.422, 0.533)$ is made using exact binomial CDFs, not using normal approximations. It is essentially the Clopper-Pearson "exact" 95% CI for $p.$

**Approximate Normal test and 95% CIs.** By contrast, a traditional approach to testing $H_0: p = 0.485$ against $H_a: p \ne 0.485$ uses a normal approximation to $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n,p).$ Then $Z = \frac{X - np}{\sqrt{npq}} = -0.3939 = \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ Thus we reject $H_0$ for a 2-sided test at level 5% if $|Z| \ge 1.96.$ The P-value of the approximate normal test is
$$P(X \le -0.3939)+P(X\ge 0.3939) = 0.697.$$

```
mu = 328*.485;  mu
[1] 159.08
sg = sqrt(mu*(1-.485)); sg
[1] 9.051309
z = (156 - mu)/sg;  z
[1] -0.3938657
2 * pnorm(-0.39)
[1] 0.6965365
```

A 95% Wald CI is of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}.$ For our example $(0.423,0.531).$

```
p.hat = 157/329
CI.wald = p.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/329)
Ci.wald
[1] 0.4232317 0.5311756
```

A somewhat more accurate 95% CI for $n$ in the hundreds is
due to Agresti and Coull: $(0.424, 0.531).$

```
p.est = (157+2)/(329+4)
CI.ac= p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/333)
CI.ac
[1] 0.4238293 0.5311256
```

In this particular problem, there is little difference between the exact binomial test and its normal approximation. Also, for practical purposes, the
confidence intervals are essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this, I am a little confused with your explanation of why we reject the null hypothesis, I thought you compare it with the Pvalue, not just the percent that is given, you compare .485, while I thought you should be comparing .783 (which is the pvalue, correct?) to .05 to actually NOT reject the null hypothesis?

Comment: Two ways to determine rejection at 5% level. (a) P-value < 5%. (b) Find critical value $c$ with 5% probability in one tail or (2.5% in two tails for 2-sided test) Reject if test statistic is beyond critical value, e.g, for z test, Rej if $Z > c = 1.645,$ $Z < -c = -1.645,$ or $|Z| > c = 1.96, for right-sided, left-sided, or 2-sided alternative, respectively. // This should be in your text and/or course notes--with examples.

Comment: We are about to get busted for 'chatting' in comments. For brevity, if there is a sentence in my answer that is unclear or you think may have a typo, please paste just that part into a Comment and say why you're confused by it.